# Passing PHP session from one directory to another created parallely in public_html

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, session-cookies

i have 3 basis directories in `public_html` directory. For example these are:

1. Directory_A  represents http://site.com
2. Directory_B  represents http://subsite-b.site.com
3. Directory_C  represents http://subsite-c.site.com

i have another directory in `public_html` named `Sessions` where i want to save the `sessions cookies` when logged users visit across the directories (site and sub-sites)

the attached picture demonstrated my directory structure clearly in `cPanel.`

[image: Directory Structure]

i face no problem to pass session between the folders and sub-folders in `Directory_A`. the problem appears when visitors switch from  `Directory_A` to `Directory_B` or `Directory_C` (visit from http://site.com to http://subsite-b.site.com or http://subsite-c.site.com) sessions are not passed at all although i set the variable `session_set_cookie_params`in every page of the above stated sub-sites like,

```
$mysession = session_name("mysession");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site.com');
session_start();
```

notable thing is that presently the variable `session.save_path` has the following configuration on my `PHP` server.

```
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
```

now, as the sessions aren't passed at all from one directory to another directory in `public_html`, i changed the configuration of `session.save_path` by pointing the path to  `public_html/Sessions`like,

```
session.save_path   /public_html/Sessions   /public_html/Sessions
```

the above change in configuration returns following similar warning in every page of http://site.com , http://subsite-b.site.com and http://subsite-c.site.com when visitors visit these sites.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/public_html/session/sess_0d38g21b3153bb4343g8d687442e76ed, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/user/public_html/Directory_B/index.php on line 4
```

on line 4 as stated in the above warning i've got the code `session_start();`

what's going wrong here? is it happening because of improper server configuration? what should i do to pass the sessions properly from one directory to another directory?

any idea or knowledge about this issue shall be well appreciated.

Comment: You should not be saving your session data in a folder that is available to me with a browser. It should be somewhere outside the public_html folder, or at least below it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your valued comment. yes, you are right there may be probability of session hijacking there in this case. i'm just proceeding through a very basic way.

Answer (score 0):

its happening because the old sessions that existed in `/tmp` you didn't copy them over. It can also mean you didn't set the permission on the directory/files to be able to read by the webserver

Comment: thanks for your valued comment. should i 'chmod` the `Session` folder in `public_html` to `0777` in this case?

Comment: your causing a big security risk in your system by exposing session on a webserver readable directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom session handler to store the sessions in a database instead of using a directory in the filesystem (e.g. /tmp).

Here's some example code: [GitHub](https://github.com/sprain/PHP-MySQL-Session-Handler), and [here's](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) some more info on using a custom session handler in PHP.

When you save the session in a database, you can access them from any site, as long as you can connect to the database. It is simpler than it sounds.

Comment: thanks. don't the `session ids` append in the query string in this case? i want to avoid `session ids` in the query string. i shall take time to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site.com');
session_start();
```

to

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site.com');
session_save_path('/home/user/public_html/Sessions');
session_start();
```

Comment: thanks for your guideline. i shall try it though i feel that the same path can be configured in `php.ini` which is more convenient.

Comment: Saving sessions in a public dir.. Are you nuts?

Comment: @edwardmp in fact `Goutam Pal` understood what i asked. the directory structure i described in my question was just an easy to understand example only.

Comment: @edwardmp Saving sessions in a public dir or any where else is not my problem.. I just give the answer what user want... You can suggest your answer but you can't give such comments to the proper answer...